# button updating state when it is not supposed to

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have almost implemented this slider button to do exactly what I want but unfortunately I have noticed a small bug. To give context, I have a home page with a slider button on it. When I press the button, it renders a new screen. I also have a bottom tab screen named Screen3. The goal is to press a button on Screen3 that moves the slider button as well as render a new screen.

I have almost successfully implemented this. At first glance when you go to Screen3 and press the text, you can see it works as I hoped. However there is a small bug and if you follow these steps you can reproduce exactly what I am referring to.

I have supplied some of the code below but this [snack demo](https://snack.expo.dev/@priedejm/slider-bug) provides everything you need. Just make sure you run it in IOS or Android

**To reproduce the bug, please do the following...**

> 1.) Click on Screen3 in the bottom tab bar and then click the text.
> It will take you to the "Map" screen as well as change the slider button. This is exactly what I want
>
> 2.) Now click on the slider button, specifically List. It will change the screen back to where
> it originally was
>
> 3.) Now for the bug, if you then click back to screen3 and then immediately click the Home page
> again on the bottom tab bar, you can see the bug I am referring to.
> It changes the button to the "Map" screen even though it is not rendered.

Here is most of the code, you might be able to debug looking at home and slider I have provided. The demo has the rest of the code.

App.js

```
function MyTabs() {
  return (

    <Stack.Navigator
     initialRouteName="Home">        
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component= {Home} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="Screen1" component= {ListHome} options={{headerShown: false}}/> 
       <Stack.Screen name="Screen2" component= {MapHome} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
    </Stack.Navigator>
);
}


export default function App() {

  return (
   <NavigationContainer>
    <Tab.Navigator
    initialRouteName="Home"
    screenOptions={{
      tabBarActiveTintColor: '#F60081',
      tabBarInactiveTintColor: '#4d4d4d',
      tabBarStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#d1cfcf',
        borderTopColor: 'transparent',
      },
    }} 
  >
    <Tab.Screen
      name="Home"
      component={MyTabs}
      options={{
        tabBarLabel: 'Home',
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
          <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={size} />
        ),
      }}
    />

     <Tab.Screen
      name="Screen3"
      component={Screen3}
      options={{
        tabBarLabel: 'Screen3',
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
          <MaterialCommunityIcons name="account-group" color={color} size={size} />
        ),
      }}
    />
    
  </Tab.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
);
}
```

Home.js

```
  const [isVisile, setIsVisible] = React.useState(true);
  const [whichComponentToShow, setComponentToShow] = React.useState("Screen1");
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if(route.params && route.params?.componentToShow) {
      setComponentToShow(route.params?.componentToShow);
      goToMap()
    }
  }, [route.params]);


  const goToMap = () => {
    setComponentToShow("Screen2");
  }

  const goToList = () => {
    setComponentToShow("Screen1");
  }

  return(
    <View style={{backgroundColor: '#d1cfcf' ,flex: 1}}>
      {whichComponentToShow === 'Screen1' && <ListHome />}
      {whichComponentToShow === 'Screen2' && <MapHome />}
      <View style={{position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, right: 1}}>
        <Top3
          renderMap={goToMap}
          renderList={goToList}
          active={route.params && route.params?.componentToShow==='Screen2'|| false}
        /> 
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

The top of slider.js

```
  
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false)
  let transformX = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

    useFocusEffect( React.useCallback(()=>{
    setActive(Boolean(props.active))
    console.log(props.active)
  },[props.active]))
```

Comment: so what is your expectation? Slider on Map and Map-Screen rendered or Slider on List and List-Screen rendered?

Comment: Visually the way it is right now is my expectation. The only thing wrong with it is what that bug points out. If you follow the steps to the bug, you will notice the slider does not match up with the correct screen

Comment: yes, I know... I followed the steps and could reproduce it. but you still didn't answer my question... "the slider does not match with the correct screen" so is the slider wrong or the screen?

Comment: The slider should be on the Map section of the button when it is on the red screen and it should be on the list section of the button when it is not. I hope that answers your question

Comment: no, it does still not answer my question... which screen do you expect to be rendered when navigating from 'Screen3' to 'Home' (step 3 of your repro steps)... Map or List... I am aware that the slider does not match the screen. But I don't know if the slider position or the screen is wrong...

Comment: On step 3, when you go from screen3 to the home bottom tab, I need the list screen rendered. You can see the slider moves to the Map section of the button even though the List screen is being rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was `useFocuseEffect` on `screen.js` file

```
...
  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      setActive(Boolean(props.active));
      console.log('focus effect running:', props.active);
    }, [props.active])
  );
...
```

This effect was being called whenever the `screen.js` mounts.

Upon removing this everything worked as expected, except, the toggling of slider when clicking the Screen3 text. Reason being the `active` prop being calculated only when prop param changes. To fix this we can

1. Move the state of `active` to `Home.js` which was responsible for detecting the params change.
2. Set the value `active` whenever the `params` changes.
3. Use this state value instead of calculating props.

```
const Home = ({ route }) => {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = React.useState(true);
  const [whichComponentToShow, setComponentToShow] = React.useState("Screen1");

  const [active, setActive] = React.useState(false); // 1.
  
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if(route.params && route.params?.componentToShow) {
      setComponentToShow(route.params?.componentToShow);
      // 2.
      if (route.params?.componentToShow === 'Screen2') {
        setActive(true);
      }
      // goToMap()
    }
  }, [route.params]);


  const goToMap = () => {
    setActive(true);
    setComponentToShow("Screen2");
  }

  const goToList = () => {
    setActive(false);
    setComponentToShow("Screen1");
  }

  return(
    <View style={{backgroundColor: '#d1cfcf' ,flex: 1}}>
      {whichComponentToShow === 'Screen1' && <ListHome />}
      {whichComponentToShow === 'Screen2' && <MapHome />}
      <View style={{position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, right: 1}}>
        <Top3
          renderMap={goToMap}
          renderList={goToList}
          active={active} 
        /> 
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Here's a working snack.
https://snack.expo.dev/0DqR-KweY

Comment: Beautiful. I appreciate the time you took to do this more than you know! Thank you